# Remove Mongo Atlas Managed x.509 sertificate from database user

Tags: mongodb

Auth sertiicate for database users are generated by mongo atlas. I want to remove x.509 setificates for specific user.

I created user and sertificate using terraform resourcen mongodbatlas_database_user and mongodbatlas_x509_authentication_database_user.

I want to be able to remove sertificates on the user using terraform or mongo command or ..

Terraform destroy on mongodbatlas_x509_authentication_database_user does not remove sertificate. And I found api call to get sertificates https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api-resources-spec/v2/#tag/X.509-Authentication/operation/createDatabaseUserCertificate but cannot find one that removes sertificates and I coould not remove sertificate using mongo atlas ui.

Comment: Simply drop the user, then the certificate becomes useless. **Client** certificates are not stored in the database anyway, they are used be the client. Or, if you use your own CA, the revoke the certificate. You cannot "remove" a certificate.